# How to fire a CDI event from a thread running in the server?

Tags: java, multithreading, event-handling, cdi, tomcat8

I want my udp server running in a thread fire an event every time it receives a datagram, sending the data formatted as json.

```
    public class UDPServer extends Thread {

        private SocketUDPCommunication comm;

        @Inject @Notify
        private StatusChangeHandler sch;

        public UDPServer() {
            comm = new SocketUDPCommunication();
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {

            DatagramPacket response;

            comm.setPort(Utils.UDP_SERVER_PORT);
            comm.createSocket();

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                System.out.println("Waiting for clients to connect on port:" + comm.getSocket().getLocalPort());
                try {
                    response = comm.receiveResponse();
                } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                    continue;
                }                           

                byte[] byteSend = comm.discardOffset(response);

                Status status = frameToJson(byteSend);

                Genson genson = new Genson();
                String json = genson.serialize(status);

                sch.sendChangedStatus(json);    //Raise the cdi event, sch not initialized!!
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void interrupt() {
            super.interrupt();
            comm.closeConnection();
        }
    }
```

There's defined a listener for this event, which will call a websocket endpoint method to broadcast this message to all connected clients:

```
    public class StatusChangeObserver {

        public void statusChanged(@Observes StatusChange sce) {
            WebsocketEndPoint.sendAll(sce.getJson());
        }
    }

    @ServerEndpoint(value="/websocket")
    public class WebsocketEndPoint {
        private static Set<Session> userSessions = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

        @OnOpen
        public void onOpen(Session userSession) {
            System.out.println("Opening new connection");
            userSessions.add(userSession);
        }

        @OnClose
        public void onClose(Session userSession) {
            System.out.println("Connection closed. Id: " + userSession.getId());
            userSessions.remove(userSession);
        }


        public static void sendAll(String message) {
            for (Session session : userSessions) {
                if (session.isOpen()) {
                    session.getAsyncRemote().sendText(message);
                }
            }     
        }
    }
```

And the handler which will actually fire the event:

```
    @Notify
    public class StatusChangeHandler {

        @Inject
        private Event<StatusChange> statusChangedEvent;

        public void sendChangedStatus(String json) {
            StatusChange sce = new StatusChange(json);
            statusChangedEvent.fire(sce);
        }
    }
```

`StatusChange` is a simple POJO which will contain the message to broadcast. The `@Notify` qualifier:

```
    @Qualifier
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
    public @interface Notify {
    }
```

These are my first steps with dependency injection, so I'm not quite sure how I should fire the event from within the thread, and how to initialize the `sch` object.
I found [this page](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#_cdi_se_module) that suggest to use `Weld` and `WeldContainer` classes to initialize CDI, but I'm not able to find this classes with maven. Is this the right approach to do it? In that case, anyone knows how to include these classes to my project?

Comment: If you're deploying to Tomcat, you'll need to use Weld Servlet https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#weld-servlet instead of Weld SE.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have public repository with weld libraries.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld

But, what did you need? in wich enviroment you will use it? For example, in wildfly, cdi 1.1 or cdi 1.2 is integrated, and you no need to add this libraries.

For more information, use http://weld.cdi-spec.org/

Comment: I'm using Tomcat8, and the maven dependency indicated in Weld's documentation is included in "pom.xml". Empty "beans.xml" is in WEB-INF, and "context.xml" in META-INF. Still, I can't import "org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld"

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on Tomcat, we are talking **servlet** environment. For that, Weld provides a servlet JAR which will automatically bootstraps CDI for you. No need to handle `Weld`/`WeldContainer` manually.

Here is a [link to Weld documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#weld-servlet) which explains which artifact/dependency you need and how to use it.

After adding that, CDI should simply bootstrap for you as you deploy your application to Tomcat.